# Log4Net static class with dynamic fieldnames

Tags: c#, log4net

In order to implement for Ninjatrader 7, I have a static Log4Net Logger in which I configure the settings. however this class is instantianted by several times by other classes. I am not able to differentiate which instance logged the information. 
Is it possible for each instance to set a configuration and then log  so I can differentiate the instance.
for eg 
Logger.setInstrument(Instrument.fullname) // it could be $EURUSD OR $EURJPY OR $GBPUSD
and then when I log using Logger.info or Logger.Error I will get the symbol prefixed with the message?

here is some sample data

```
2016-06-04 15:04:53,163 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:16 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123
```

2016-06-04 15:04:53,164 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:17 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,164 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:18 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,165 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:19 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,165 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:19 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,166 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:20 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,166 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:20 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,167 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:22 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,167 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:22 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,168 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:23 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,169 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:23 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,169 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:24 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,170 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:25 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

2016-06-04 15:04:53,170 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   5/30/2016 4:04:25 AM123 123 wait4longpullback 123

```
  public static class Logger
{
    private static log4net.ILog Log { get; set; }

    static Logger()
    {
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders(); /*Remove any other appenders*/

        FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
        fileAppender.AppendToFile = true;
        fileAppender.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
        fileAppender.File = @"c:\temp\logevents.txt";
        PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout();
        pl.ConversionPattern = "%d [%2%t] %-5p [%-10c]   %m%n%n";
        pl.ActivateOptions();
        fileAppender.Layout = pl;
        fileAppender.ActivateOptions();

        log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileAppender);
        //Test logger
        // Log =LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


        Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Logger));
    }

    public static void Error(object msg)
    {
        Log.Error(msg);
    }

    public static void Error(object msg, Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(msg, ex);
    }

    public static void Error(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
    }

    public static void Info(object msg)
    {
        Log.Info(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logger class is static. What do you mean with it being instantiated multiple times? A static class is only instantiated once for the application context.

Comment: what I meant is that there will be multiple instances of Indicator class which will call Logger object. I want to be able to differentiate which instance of Indicator class is related to which line of the log. for ex the Indicator instance($EURUSD) calls Logger.info(message) I want the prefix $EURUSD along with the message in the log.

Comment: Store an ID for each instance of Indicator in the instance, and provide it as parameter to your logging methods.

Comment: Are the multiple instances in different threads, or all in the same thread?

Comment: they will be in different threads

Comment: Your question isn't very clear but if the instances are in different threads then a solution might be to use [log4net's ThreadContext object](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html) to set a per-thread property - `log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["identifier"] = "$EURUSD"` which you can add to your ConversionPattern as `%property{identifier}`

Comment: wow, this is very cool. I added the following as 
   `pl.ConversionPattern = "%d [%2%t] %-5p [%-10c]   %m%n%n %property{identifier} " ; `
and my log looks like better for me to differentiate. I thought the $EURJPY  should appear after the datetime
`$EURJPY 2016-06-04 17:08:36,622 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   6/3/2016 5:09:33 PM120 120 wait4shortpullback SHORT `

 $EURJPY 2016-06-04 17:08:36,623 [NT main thread] INFO  [NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger]   6/3/2016 5:09:33 PM121 121 watchforshortbounce SHORT